# Chrome onMessage not working (?)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've read about onMessage.addListener method in Chrome to pass some data from extensions to script. What I have now:
**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('searchButton').onclick = searchText;
};
function searchText(){
  var search = document.getElementById('searchText').value; // f.ex "123"
  if(search){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{file:search.js});
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{method:'search',searchText:search});
    });
  }
}
```

**search.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  alert('text');
});
```

However, alert ('text') is never fired. What's the problem?

Comment: You should quote "search.js"...

Comment: chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id,{file:"search.js"}); ? - That doesn't work for me.

Comment: And put the `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` call in the callback of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

Comment: Hm..could you please post edited code as an answer? I think I don't understand you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should quote "search.js" and put the [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-sendMessage) call in the callback of [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript):

```js
function searchText(){
    var search = document.getElementById('searchText').value; // f.ex "123"
    if (search) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
                file: 'search.js'
            }, function() {
                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                    method: 'search',
                    searchText: search
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

If this suggestion does not help, [inspect the popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html#inspect-popup) and look for error messages.

Comment: Well, that hasn't help me, but I think there's something wrong with popup.js.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with popup.js. And no error messages in inspector

Comment: @Kondra007 Did you [declare](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html) the [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html) permission in the manifest file (or at least host permissions to access the page)? This is required for using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`.

Comment: Yes, I've set "permissions": [
  "tabs", "activeTab"
  ],

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you've given. If you want any further help, you need to show all of your relevant code (manifest.json, popup.html, popup.js, search.js). Did you reload your extension **and the page** after editing your code?

Comment: I've edited the question. And yes, I've reloaded everything :)

Comment: You didn't look at the popup's inspector at all... If you did, you would clearly see an error like "Cannot set property 'onclick' of null"... The ID you've passed to `document.getElementById` doesn't match any element with the given ID in the document.

Comment: Oh, I've edited it again, I renamed some variables here. IDs are correct now, but still not working

Comment: @Kondra007 `popup.js` still contains the same errors as in my answer. Did you read or use my answer at all...? >_>

Comment: My inspector doesn't see any errors. `<input type="text" id="textfield"><br>` --> `var search = document.getElementById('textfield').value;` and `<input id="btn_search" value="Search" type="button">` --> `document.getElementById('btn_search').onclick = searchText;`

Comment: The popup.js from your question is still wrong. Are you looking at the right console?